# Compound string from multiple input fields

Tags: jquery

I have a 3 input fields. 2 for values and one fild for result.

```
    <input type="text" value="" id="name">
    <input type="text" value="" id="surn">

    <input type="text" value="" id="result">
```

In the results of the first two zancheniya fields must be joined.
For example

1 - John

2 - Smith

3 (result) John Smith

I have solution for one field http://jsfiddle.net/LvZdL/1/

```
  $("input#name").keyup(function () {
      var name  = $(this).val();
      $("input#result").val(name);
  }).keyup();
```

Comment: Whats the final `.keyup();` for ?

Comment: @ManseUK It probably triggers the handler on the initial page load, so any initial value in those fields is handled correctly.

Comment: @GregL thanks - you learn something new everyday :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$("input#name,input#surn").keyup(function () {
      var name  = $("input#name").val();
      var surname  = $("input#surn").val();
      $("input#result").val(name + ' ' + surname);
  }).keyup();
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fx256/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just updated the jQuery selector to select both fields and also get the text form both fields :

```
$("input#name,input#surn").keyup(function () {
      var name  = $('input#name').val() +" "+ $('input#surn').val();
      $("input#result").val(name);
  }).keyup();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/LvZdL/2/